# Match up (with) vs Match

Tags: american-english

I've looked in the dictionary about the meaning of these 2 words, but I can still not process how they're different.

For example, when should I use **up**? If the word **match up** means the same as **match** already?

> The prices in-store do not **match** with the prices online.
>
> The prices in-store do not **match up** with the prices online. (*Not very sure whether this is natural speech*).
>
> When are our time zones ever going to **match**? (*Be equal*)
>
> When is our time zone ever going to **match up with** each other? (*Not sure about this one either*).

Answer (score 1):

All of these are perfectly good, the difference is stylistic and local idiom.

It's very similar to **head an organisation** and **head up an organisation**: identical in meaning, slightly different in style.

(But the differening time zones are plural: "When **are** our time zone**s** ever going to match/match up")